# Javascript/jQuery attach different function args to .click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with this code? Reading this it seems that for each loop the jquery should attach a function with assigned values for each iteration. Instead it's attaching i = 2 to every object. Why is it doing that and how can I get it to attach the expected values (e.g., 0, 1, ...)?

```
//data.length is 2.

for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    // Attach the click function
    linkId = 'a#' + pk;
    $(linkId).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(i, pk, data);
    });
};
```

console.log -- each link has the same parameters

```
2 "52fef25e391a56206f03be6e" [object Array]
```

Comment: Classical closure+loop confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming that a block creates a new variable scope. It doesn't in JavaScript. Only a function execution does.

If you use `$.each()` instead, the callback you give it will be invoked for each iteration, and so you'll have a new scope for every one.

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
                //    ^---^---function parameters are local to this scope

//   v--declare a variable local to this scope
    var linkId = 'a#' + pk;

                //   v--the function made in this scope can access the local vars
    $(linkId).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(i, pk, data, linkId, data[i]);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very helpful and I've used your answer to solve my problem at hand. Thank you. However, for knowledge's sake, to get my original code to work, is it possible to declare variables within the scope of each iteration? I tried that but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @TechMedicNYC: No, not without a function invocation of some sort. Blocks alone in JS simply don't define any type of variable scope. The next version of JS will have block scope by declaring variables with the `let` keyword. This is available today in Firefox as well as the newest versions of Chrome (when a flag is set) and I believe IE11.

Answer (score 2):

console will be displayed only when you click the `$(linkId)` but at the time is is already equal to `data.length` (aka 2 in your case) so it will always display 2

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate the variable's scope. Declare a `var j = i;` inside the loop context so it enters the click-callback's scope.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to create a separate scope for each iteration you can also use ordinary closure-functions, and pass current `i` into it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function(j) {
        $('a#' + pk).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(j, pk, data);
        });
    })(i);
};
```